# Random distribution conditioned by a Gaussian distribution

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Given a set of points (black dots on the picture - [see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mAt1y.png)) with initial positions on a curve of a function y(x) (in this case a Gaussian density function  - [see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mAt1y.png)) along the Y-axis, is it possible to assign to each point (x, y(x)) a time period  $\tau(x)$ (for example to reach a common target, located at $y_{target}$ - the thick horizontal  bar in the image), such that

1. $\tau(x_i)$ < $\tau(x_j)$ if $y(x_i)$ > $y(x_j)$
2. mean($\tau$) = $\tau_{avg}$ where $\tau_{avg}$ is given

In other words, it is possible to find a distribution ($\tau(x)$) satisfying both conditions above?

Edit 1: If assumed that $\forall x, y(x) \in [0,1]$, then $\tau$ will be such that the probability of observing $\tau_i$ is $y_i$. Hence $\int y(x)\tau(x)dx$ = $\tau_{avg}$. This is where I get stuck.

PS: Setting $\tau(x)$ = $y_{target}$ - $y(x)$ satisfies the first condition, but does not guarantee the required mean.

Many thanks !

Comment: What have you tried? is there a passage in particular where you got stuck?

Comment: @Exodd thanks for your comment. Just edited my question.

Answer (score 1):

Notice that if $c>0$, then 
$$
\tau_c(x) = c(y_{target} - y(x))
$$
still respect the first condition, and you can set $c$ to obtain the wanted average. For example, your $\tau(x)$ is my $\tau_1(x)$. Since the mean is linear, then
$$
mean(\tau_c(x)) = c\cdot mean(\tau) 
$$
so by setting $c = \tau_{avg}/mean(\tau)$ you have done.